# Hodge numbers of Kummer varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian surface. And consider the Hilbert scheme $A^{[n]}$ of $n$ points on $A$, which is a desingularisation of the $n$-th symmetric product $S^nA$. We have a composed map 
$$
\varphi:A^{[n]}\to S^nA\to A\,,
$$
where the second map is the sum.

We now define $K^{[[n]]}:=\varphi^{-1}(0)$.

> **Question:** Has anybody computed the Hodge numbers of $K^{[[n]]}$?

I know that Lothar Göttsche has worked on closely related things. But I was unable to find precisely what I am looking for.

EDIT: 1) any information about low-dimension examples is very welcome!

2) a formula exists (by Göttsche-Soergel, see comments below) but in order to get actual numbers one should probably use a computer.

Comment: In the paper by Göttsche and  Soergel, Math. Ann. 1993, I believe
they compute the Hodge numbers of $S^{[n]}$ for any surface, but you
probably knew this, and it isn't quite what you want. If someone doesn't answer in a day or two, I'll think about it when I have more time.



Comment: Here are some more things you probably already know. First, since these varieties are hyperk\"ahler, they have $h^{1,0}=h^{0,1}=0$ and $h^{2,0}=h^{0,2}=1$. Second, the cohomology group H^2 carries the structure of a lattice, and in fact (see arxiv:1012.4155, Prop 3.2) it is isomorphic to the lattice 3U+<-2(n+1)> (U=hyperbolic plane), so has rank 7; therefore $h^{1,1}=5$.

Comment: @Artie Prendergast-Smith: I am a beginner in that subject, and I actually didn't know about $h^{1,1}=5$. Thank you for that. 

Comment: @Donu Arapura: yes, I was told (very) recently about that paper. This is true that there is a formula (this is Corollary 1 -of Theorems 6 and 7- of the paper) but I must admit that at the moment I find it diffucult to make computations with it (but this only tells you about my incompetence - the formula is really nice). 

Comment: Dear Damien, you're welcome. I'm a little confused by your edit 2): Donu seems to be saying that Goettsche--Soergel give a formula for the Hodge numbers of the Hilbert scheme of points on a surface, rather than Kummer varieties as in your question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dear Artie, the largest part of Goettsche--Soergel's paper is devoted to Hilbert schemes of surfaces, but actually I think that Section 6 of that paper is devoted to Kummer varieties (but I don't have access to it now... I'll check next week). 

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll be glad to learn about what the formula says if you have a chance to post it here!

Comment: I had a chance to check (I hadn't looked at it for a long time)
and indeed  Göttsche and Soergel give a formula for the Hodge structure of a Kummer variety in theorem 7. So isn't that the answer?
